# Once we create trigger in php page then do we need to create same in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I am using Mysql for database purpose for my php code.

I have created trigger in php code as below, Now do I need to create it in mysql??

My following insert data into table, and also show content of tables. But action I performed in trigger does not make any change. Is there any problem in trigger?

Once it started working fine but after i changed table name it stopped working though I kept table name same my php page and mysql.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$id=$_POST['id'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$city=$_POST['city'];

$con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306' ,'root','root','my_db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql1="select * from student";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
echo "<table border='1'>

<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>City</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; 

**$sql3 = "CREATE TRIGGER MysqlTrigger AFTER INSERT ON student FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO details VALUES ($id,$fname,$lname,$city);";**
mysqli_query($con,$sql3);


$sql5="INSERT INTO student (id,fname, lname, city)
VALUES
('$_POST[id]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[city]')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql5);

echo "1 record added";

print "<h2>After performing Trigger updated table details</h2>";
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>City</th>
</tr>";

$sql4="select * from details";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql4);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))

{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; 

mysqli_close($con);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sentence is extremely contradictory...."after i changed table name it stopped working though I kept table name same my php page and mysql"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - no, you don't have to because creating it in the code also creates it in MySQL.  But you have bigger problems.

Longer answer -

Triggers are part of the database, and typically you wouldn't create a trigger from code.  You would create triggers the same way you create tables - create them once in MySQL and they stick around until you drop them.

Technically the code you have will work, but the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement will only succeed the first time it is called.  In subsequent executions of that script the `CREATE TRIGGER` will error out because the trigger already exists.  But since you aren't checking for errors, your script will probably continue on happily.

Also, the way your trigger is made, it will always insert the same record into the `details` table that was inserted when the trigger was created.

Finally, you have some serious security issues with your code:

1. You are directly using `POST` variables in SQL which opens you up to SQL Injection
2. Whatever user your site is running as probably shouldn't have permissions to execute DDL statements like `CREATE TRIGGER`